# How to restore a TFS workspace and pending changes to a newly installed hard drive?

Tags: workspace

On my system, I have two hard drives; C and D. TFS 2010 installed on C and my TFS workspace installed on D to the Workspaces folder.

Drive D: failed and I had pending changes in the workspace that I do not wish to lose.

Since my C drive is okay, it is possible to recreate the workspace with all the pending changes?

Comment: Will this work for you? > Create new workspace on C -> get latest -> overwrite the files you want from D -> check them out -> shelve pending changes

Comment: The problem is no backup to overwrite from. I use online backup and since the Workspaces folder was new since the backup was installed, it was not coninuously backed up.

Comment: If all pending changes kept locally on the failed HDD, I don't think it's possible to retrieve them. If the HDD is still alive you may try running Recuva or similar recovery tool

Answer (score 3):

Workspaces only keep a record that a file has changed, it does not record what those changes are. So you won't be able to get the Pending Changes from the other drive unless you created a Shelveset as a backup.